# Run File From Address Using hostname

Tags: javascript, jquery

there is a script I'm trying to use for Blogger. It works when you enter your domain URL into the src, but I'm trying to find a way to do it using hostname to insert the domain.

Original script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?YourBlogUrl=INSERT-YOUR-URL-HERE&amp;ShowHowMany=5&amp;_id=390e906036f48772b2ed4b5d837af4cd&amp;_callback=getYpipePP&amp;_render=json" />
```

I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var excuteTopCommentators = "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?YourBlogUrl=http://'+window.location.hostname+'&amp;ShowHowMany=5&amp;_id=390e906036f48772b2ed4b5d837af4cd&amp;_callback=getYpipePP&amp;_render=json"
    return excuteTopCommentators
</script>
```

I also tried document.write:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?YourBlogUrl=http://'+window.location.hostname+'&amp;ShowHowMany=5&amp;_id=390e906036f48772b2ed4b5d837af4cd&amp;_callback=getYpipePP&amp;_render=json"></script>');
</script>
```

Neither of the attempts seem to work. Any ideas on how to do this without manually inserting the domain URL into the script src?

Comment: What you see in developer console? downloads the file? im intrested in your second attemp.

Comment: Illegal return statement and Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is that you get the script, but it is never executed.

Maybe try jQuery's getScript http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

```
function getIt() {
  return $.getScript('http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?YourBlogUrl=http://'+window.location.hostname+'&amp;ShowHowMany=5&amp;_id=390e906036f48772b2ed4b5d837af4cd&amp;_callback=getYpipePP&amp;_render=json');
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, and showed no errors in the chrome console.

Comment: Try opening the script directly in the browser URL bar. Can you rule out whether the script exists?

Comment: The script works when I manually enter in my Domain URL. It doesn't work when I try to use hostname.

Comment: perhaps you should check that ``window.location.hostname`` is the same as your static domain url. It probably is missing the protocol - as in http://

Comment: "perhaps" !? What are they talking about ?, make pure speculation. I've done the research and the correct answer is JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

Your second option looks fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?YourBlogUrl=http://'+window.location.hostname+'&amp;ShowHowMany=5&amp;_id=390e906036f48772b2ed4b5d837af4cd&amp;_callback=getYpipePP&amp;_render=json"></script>');
</script>
```

The script is downloaded but do nothing. **this is because it is a JSONP, not an script**

So, you need a callback function to get it working: **(note that is data, not code)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // JSONP Callback
    function getYpipePP(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }

    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?YourBlogUrl=http://'+window.location.hostname+'&amp;ShowHowMany=5&amp;_id=390e906036f48772b2ed4b5d837af4cd&amp;_callback=getYpipePP&amp;_render=json"></script>');

</script>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/HhYZtH09EcdPZbwS9rfq?p=preview

Look the query, say `_callback=getYpipePP` and `_render=json`

**Related:** [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

Comment: Didn't work: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. I suspect it may have something to do with the fact that this is a XML template. I tried adding CDATA tags to your script, but then got the error illegal token.

Comment: @Xarcell its works, you are fetching a JSONP OBJECT not an script. see the plunker, and see the fetched data, just call a function called getYpipePP and pass an JSON object as parameter. Just that jsonp does.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't. The output is `');` and it throws the error in the console.

Comment: It's a shame you do not see the answer to your problem when you have it in front of your eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (the problem you're having is the end "script" tag):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('<script language="javascript" src="http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?YourBlogUrl=http://'
                     + window.location.hostname
                     + '&amp;ShowHowMany=5&amp;_id=390e906036f48772b2ed4b5d837af4cd&amp;_callback=getYpipePP&amp;_render=json" type="text/javascript"><\/script>')
    </script>
```